# Finding canonical form for orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ linear operator in Euclidean space, such that in standard basis represented by the matrix:

A = $\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1/2 & -\sqrt 2/2 \\1/2 & 1/2 & \sqrt 2/2\\\sqrt 2/2 & -\sqrt 2/2 & 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Prove that $\varphi$ is ar rotation of an axis, find the axis and the angle of the rotation - is it right rotation or left rotation?

So I know that $det A=1$, and $1$ has to be an eigenvalue of the canonical matrix (and $det$ of rotation block is also 1), but i don't know how to continue from here..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

note that an eigenvector of the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ is $(1,1,0)^T$, so the space spanned by this vector is the axis of rotation ( ''fixed'' vectors of the rotation).

Now you can use a nice vector orthogonal to this eigenspace and calculate the rotation, or you can use the [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) for a  rotation matrix around a given axis to find the angle.

---

The unit vector in the direction of the axis of rotation is:
$$
\vec u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so the first column of the matrix of general rotation is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta+\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos \theta)\\ \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos \theta)\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin \theta}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and this gives the angle of rotation $\theta$ such that 
$$
\cos \theta =0 \quad \land \quad \sin \theta = 1
$$
that is a rotation of an angle of $90°$ counterclockwise around the axis $\vec u$.

Comment: The right vector is $(1,1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you! I had an error sign in my calculations :)  Edit

Comment: Ok, so I found that the angle is 90°, so the canonical matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}cos  90 & -sin 90 & 0 \\sin 90 & cos 90 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix} $  and I know that the orthogonal complement to the eigenspace of eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ is $Span\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1 \\ -2  \end{pmatrix}\}$. Now how do I find the axis and the direction of the rotation?

Comment: The angle of rotation is $90°$, but the matrix in your comment is a rotation around the $x$ axis. Actually the axis of the rotation in OP is different: it is the axis that contain the eigenvector of the eigenvalue $1$. I've added something to may answer.